# Angular2: set parameters as query parameters on Http.Request

Tags: angular

I'm extending Angular2 `Http.Request` class in order to create my own `Request` classes.

```
export class AuthzCodeRequest extends Request {

        private static get OAUTH2_RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAMETER():string { return "response_type"; }
        private static get OAUTH2_RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAMETER_VALUE():string { return "code"; }

        constructor (authz_path: string, client_id: string, client_secret: string, username: string, password: string)
        {
            this.createParameters();
        }

        private createParameters(authz_path: string, client_id: string, client_secret: string, username: string, password: string)
        {
            this.url = authz_path; //here
        }
}
```

How to set parameters as query parameters instead on headers ??

Answer (score 0):

Upto my asumption you want to send your parameters may be username or password via parameter not in header part of http request so you can easily send by appending to url like this

```
export class AuthzCodeRequest extends Request {

        private static get OAUTH2_RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAMETER():string { return "response_type"; }
        private static get OAUTH2_RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAMETER_VALUE():string { return "code"; }

        constructor (authz_path: string, client_id: string, client_secret: string, username: string, password: string)
        {
            this.createParameters();
        }

        private createParameters(authz_path: string, client_id: string, client_secret: string, username: string, password: string)
        {
            this.url = '..authz_path_url/?username='+username+'&password='+password;

        }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to set them up? Isn't there any more elegant way to do that?

Comment: either you can append your parameters in your component class and pass just `url` as parameter to this method this could be also option, its upto you which is best to use case